# Laravel restrict users to only be able to see their own profile

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to be able to restrict users to only be able to see their own profiles in my laravel project. So when a user wants to access their profile, they would go to the url followed by /userprofile/{id}. But as of right now, any user can type in the specific id of a different user and access their profile. So if I'm logged in as the first user to register, I would have an id of 1. But I only want to be able to access my profile. If I try to type in id 2 or 3 in the url I want it to kick me back to the homepage. Any idea how I could accomplish this? Using some sort of middleware perhaps?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use App\User;
use App\Salutation;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $users_info = User::all();
        return view('userprofile.index', compact("users_info"));
    }

    public function show($user_info){
        $user_info = User::find($user_info);
        return view('userprofile.show', compact("user_info"));
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('userprofile.create');
    }

    public function store(UserRequest $request){
        $formData = $request->all();

        User::create($formData);

        return redirect('userprofile');
    }

    public function edit($user_info) {
        $user_info = User::findOrFail($user_info);

        return view('userprofile.edit', compact("user_info"));
    }

    public function update(UserRequest $request, $user_info){
        $formData = $request->all();
        $user_info = User::findOrFail($user_info);
        $user_info->update($formData);

        return redirect('userprofile');
    }

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth', ['only' =>['create', 'edit', 
'destroy']]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your controller look like? Instead of doing something like `return User::find($id)`, you'd do `return Auth::user()`. That's all there is to it really.

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to handle this.  Could be what devk said, could be checking that the Auth::id() matches the requested id, or you could use the Gate/Authorization logic built into Laravel and write a policy for accessing this endpoint.  Have you read through Laravel's documentation?

Comment: I just posted my User controller. Also would there be a way to do it where I could simply check if the request id is the same as the current logged in users id, and if it isnt, kick them back to the homepage? That's why I asked if middleware could work.

Comment: You need to query the profile page user id and compare it with the logged in user and allow or redirect access based on the comparison outcome.

Comment: The easy solution is to do `abort_unless($user_info == \Auth::id(), 403)` in `show`

Comment: @apokryfos In my controller method or in my view?

Comment: @user80137 in `show` i.e. in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just compare the current user with param id

example:

```
public function getProfile(Request $request, $id)
{
     if(Auth::id() == $id) {
          // valid user
          $user_info = Auth::user();
          return view('userprofile.show', compact("user_info"));
     } else {
          //not allowed
     }
}
```